# Order of the group $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt[7]3, \zeta)/ \Bbb Q(\sqrt[7]3))$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\Bbb Q = F$. For polynomial $x^7-3$, the splitting field is $E=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[7]3, \zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is seventh root of unity. $\text{Aut}(E/F)$ is a group of $F$-[automorphism](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:F-Homomorphism) of $E$. A proposition in my note tells the order of Aut$(E/F)$ is $[E:F] = 42$.

Is order of Aut$(E/\Bbb Q(\sqrt[7]3))$ 6? Since $E$ is splitting field of degree 6 polynomial $1+x + \dots +x^6 \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]3)[x]$
?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $E/\Bbb Q(\sqrt[7]3)$ is a Galois extension of degree $6$. Its Galois group has order $6$.

In fact its Galois group is cyclic, its elements are $\sigma_k$
($1\le k\le 6$) where $\sigma_k:\zeta\to\zeta^k$ (compare cyclotomic
extensions of $\Bbb Q$).

The extension is generated by $\zeta$ whose minimum polynomial
is the seventh cyclotomic polynomial, viz., $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.